# Elasticsearch - Reindex whole cluster using pattern for new index name

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with thousands of indices, with 5 shards per index.
I would like to reindex them with only 1 shard per index.

Is there a build in solution in Elastic to reindex for instance all the indices by adding "-reindexed" to each index ?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you want to dynamically change the index names while reindexing.

Let's understand this with an example:

1) Add some indices:

```
POST sample/_doc/1
{
  "test" : "sample"
}

POST sample1/_doc/1
{
  "test" : "sample"
}

POST sample2/_doc/1
{
  "test" : "sample"
}
```

2) Use [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex) to dynamically change the index names while reindexing multiple indices:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "sample*"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": ""
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._index = ctx._index + '-reindexed'"
  }
}
```

The above request will reindex all the indices starting with ***sample*** and add ***-reindexed*** in their indexNames. So that means **sample**, **sample1** and **sample2** will be reindexed as **sample-reindexed**, **sample1-reindexed** and **sample2-reindexed** all with this one request.

> In order to set up the destination indices with one shard you need to
>   create those indices before reindexing.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, sounds good. Ill try to combine your method and a template with shard=1

Comment: That should work. Let me know if you need any more help :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do a simple `reindex` but I'd also recommend you take a look at the `Shrink Index` API:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/indices-shrink-index.html

The documentation above links to v7.0, but this has been around for many iterations.

In your example, you would do something similar to the following:

First, reallocate copies of all primary or replica shards to a single node and prevent any future write-access while the shrink operations are being performed.

```
PUT /my_source_index/_settings
{
  "settings": {
    "index.routing.allocation.require._name": "shrink_node_name", 
    "index.blocks.write": true 
  }
}
```

Initiate the shrink operation, clear the index settings set in the previous command, and update your primary and replica settings on the target index:

```
POST my_source_index/_shrink/my_target_index-reindexed
{
  "settings": {
    "index.routing.allocation.require._name": null, 
    "index.blocks.write": null,
    "index.number_of_replicas": 1,
    "index.number_of_shards": 1, 
    "index.codec": "best_compression"
  }
}
```

Note the above is also allocating a replica shard - if you don't want this, ensure you set this to 0.

You would want to set up a script of some sort to iterate through the list of source indices one by one.

Comment: Thanks. Im mainly looking for a build in solution without a script which loops.